# Reduce DC voltage using a resistor..is there a specific reduction relationship?

Tags: dc

Hi I have encountered an issue with a vehicle and isolated remedy down to coolant sensor/ecu. Basically the ECU sends 5 volts down one wire through the coolant sensor and returns to ecu. As the sensor warms the return voltage reduces and based on this the ECU determines fuel delivery/ fuel injector opening cycle.It is primarily during cranking that this equation is important. 
I want to trick the ECU into believing the car is always 15 degrees lower that reality. If I solder a resistor into circuit would this have the effect Im looking for ? If so is there a specific relationship as to voltage drop/resistor rating ?

Comment: A resistor is designed to reduce current, not drop voltage. Yes, it will have a voltage drop across it but that varies depending on the current. Using a resistor to reduce the voltage is not reliable. Why are you trying to trick the ECU? Why not just fix the faulty part? Modifying certain parts of your car can be very dangerous, if not illegal.

Comment: It really depends on what your sensor is, if its resistive or if its something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, I suspect that the closest arrangement, to what you are looking at, is something like the following (taken from Schwaller A. E., Total Automotive Technology, 2005, USA, New York: Thomas Delmar Learning.)

[image: Car coolant circuit, including computer]

What you say you want is to subtract 15F from the reading. But this is really going to be a table of values used by the MCU to estimate temperatures. And, unfortunately, the value of the resistor used in the computer is unknown right now, as is the temperature to resistance table for the sensor unit (I'm assuming it is a two-wire device.) Finally, a simple subtraction of a fixed temperature is probably not so easy as the addition of some single resistor value. You may need to accept some kind of compromise here in order to gain simplicity. What kind of compromises are acceptable?

Can you collect some information about your system? Is it indeed a two-wire sensor system as shown in the chart above? (This seems to match what you are talking about... but it's best that we agree about it.) Also, can you find out any detailed specifications about your sensing unit? Would you be able to consider hooking up a \$4.7k\Omega\$ resistor (and perhaps several other values, too) to the location where the sensor goes and measure the voltage across it and report that information? (I'm assuming that with the sensor disconnected you read exactly \$5V\$ at the computer port for the sensor. But could you tell me, for sure, if that is indeed what you measure?)

Finally, if it is the case that you can consider the idea of adding another fan motor to your situation, you might think about the idea of tapping into your existing sensor (in parallel to the MCU), feeding the signal into a different controller unit. There are very cheap PID devices available on ebay, for example, which can run off of 12V, include relays, and where you can accept 0-5V input signals, provide a set point threshold for the new fan that is different from the MCU settings, and even provide hysteresis through the use of the P term in the controller (disabling the I and D terms.) I don't know if that has any interest, because I'm a little flummoxed by exactly what you are trying to achieve. But I thought I'd toss this one out there, as well, just in case it may matter.

Comment: Yes you have captured the situation perfectly above.

Comment: I tried fitting a relay including starter trigger to cut off sensor whilst cranking

Comment: This I thought would temporarily disable sensor and initiate default mode (under 15 degrees) during cranking. Unfortuately it failed miserably and seemed to affect resistance reading

Comment: @Freelander: Thanks for the update and that this situation is close to what you are dealing with. I'll edit my answer shortly. But I have couple of things to do first. In the meantime, you are basically trying to force the MCU into a certain mode when starting the car?

Comment: Yes providing the car thinks its colder than it is it supplies superior fuel and injector settings thus improving starting

Comment: @Freelander: It would be nice to take those measurements I mentioned. And also to actually measure the resistance of your sensor at some (any) convenient temperature, as well. (Two temperatures would be better [stick it into hot water?]) Can you do some or any of that? It may not be needed. But if it isn't too hard, that might be nice to have.

Comment: @Freelander:  Or perhaps, what voltage does it read when cold (and not providing you your superior results) and what voltage does it read when you managed to get it to do what you wanted? Can you take those two measurements?

Comment: Here are the reading I got With the ignition OFF the resistance (ohms / Kohms) between the two terminals of the PLUG is 1.028
With the ignition OFF the resistance (ohms / Kohms) between the two terminals of the actual sensor 2.28 and coolant temperature at time 26 degrees
With ignition key on the voltage between two terminals of plug is 5.03v. I get same 5.03 between blue/white and ground.
Hope these readings make sense.

Comment: @Freelander: Are you taking resistance measurements with everything hooked up or voltage readings? (I'm sorry I can't tell from your writing.) Or did you remove the sensor and take readings of the sensor itself separated from the circuit?

Comment: They are resistance  readings taken in situ on car. The plug disconnected from sensor and ignition off reads 1.028. The readings taken from coolant sensor terminals (whilst it is fitted to engine) measures 2.28. The coolant temperature at the time was 26 degrees. Thenext readings were voltage readings

Comment: @Freelander: Okay. So when cold, the plug terminals read 5.03V. That's as high as it gets, if my picture is correct. (Cold means the sensor is at its highest resistance, as hotter means lower resistance and therefore lower voltage reading.) So it is going to be _hard_ to change that cold reading. Can you disconnect the sensor, turn on the ignition (don't start the car), and read the voltage that the MCU is trying to supply to the sensor -- but without the sensor present?

Comment: Hi It is sending 5 volts down the wire in that situation.

Comment: Ive just been out and experimented with that potentiometer rig I made. I first of all took the correct temperature of coolant using  diagnostic tool. It read 25.5 degrees. I then fitted the potentiometer rig between one of the two wires and the switch terminal. I adjusted it to read 15 degrees less (10.5 degrees). I then brought the rig into house and measured resistance between both ends. I set the multimeter to resistance setting and chose 200. It reads a resistance of 2.1 . Does this mean that if I buy a resistor of that rating it will replicate this minus 15 degree effect ?

Comment: @Freelander: Then I don't think there is much you can do. When cold, your MCU is getting the highest possible voltage (and as high as it is able to read, I suspect.) There is no way to make it think that the engine is any colder than that. It just reads a voltage. Your voltage, cold, is at the maximum the MCU can read. There is not much to be done, I fear. Yet you claim to have done something that is successful. Honestly, I'm at a bit of a loss. I'm missing something important. Maybe I'm just not focused enough and someone else will catch it.

Comment: @Freelander: Perhaps the enrichment you are talking about actually occurs when the temperature rises and you got that wrong (not that it would make any sense, at all.... but I'm flummoxed for now and just grasping for straws.)

Comment: Hi Jonk, No I have been using the rig for some time as workaround and it does control the temperature quite precisely. This evening was the first time I have used it with sensor connected and it still produced same result. I am not familiar with resistors but good at following instructions. Is there a resistor available that will equate to this 2.1 reading ?

Comment: @Freelander: I feel horrible suggesting anything knowing full well that I really don't know why what you are doing helps you. But there is a standard resistor value at 2.2k (assuming you are talking about kOhm here.) You can also get one easily at 1.8k, too. I wish I understood why it helps you.

Comment: Jonk I have spnt 4 months not understanding this car no wonder you are confused :) Anyway you have honestly been great help . Im now very hopefull that if I solder a 2.2k resistor into the circuit it will represent a -15 degree reading.

Comment: One final pieice of advice I need though. Will I need specific 2.2k resistor ? I quickly had a look and they seem to have a Watt reference. What do I need ?

Comment: @Freelander: The current will be just a few thousands of an amp. So pretty much ANY wattage will do. Get something that is sized conveniently for your hands and the working space. It will be more than large enough, regarding watts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a specific relationship, Ohm's Law. Voltage = Current x Resistance. It's at the base of all electronics. As far as your proposed solution with your vehicle, I doubt it will work. It's impossible to answer your question without more information about the specifics of the components involved, and even then the answer would very likely be no. Most likely it would just make the problem worse.

Comment: The coolant sensor

Comment: Ive had extensive tests done on vehicle to remedy but to no avail. Injectors fuel pumps sensors etc all checked out fine but cranking still have issues at higher temps. No definite conclusion but potentially the ecu has currupt file. This query is my low cost workaround.  The temperature of the coolant sensor has a direct relationship with the ECU. when coolant is at 15 degrees or below the ECU provides maximum fuel mixture and car starts perfectly.It also defaults to this setting when sensor disconnected.I have fitted a switch to take advantage of this and disconnect before cranking.

Comment: My hope is that I could solder something into circuit rather than have a manual switch. apologies for lack of knowledge on electronics Im out of my comfort zone.

Comment: if the ECU has a corrupt file, modifying the behaviour of one of the circuits its connected to will have highly unpredictable results. Even though there's a simple relationship regarding resistors and current and voltage, there's no predicting how a complicated system like a computer will interact with it when it's not possible to see the computer code.

Comment: Previous to fitting the switch I made a small rig with two potentiometers and a resistor. I fitted this to coolant sensor plug and could adjust temperature to whichever setting I wished. The ECU was fine with this and behaved accordingly. i.e provided more fuel at lower temps. I trialled it for couple weeks to ensure no ill effects. It was cumbersome though hence switch and now my newest idea.

Comment: If you've already found a resistance that sets the temperature you want, why not just take that resistance value and put it permanently in the circuit? It sounds like you've already figured this out?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but please bear with me as probably have explained myself fully. I used the rig purely to artificially reduce temp to below 15 degrees and get car to start.Once started I want the car to retake control and revert to take true readings from sensor. I believe if I can get it to permanently read 15 degrees below true temp it will be issuing that little bit extra fuel encouraging car to start.The rig I made had a 100ohms resistor plus 2 linear potentiometers. a 10k ; 1k. How can I work out what strength of resistor would give this result ?

Comment: So potentiometers are just variable resistors, when you turn the dial on the potentiometer you're changing the resistance. the 10k and 1k value for the potentiometers are the maximum resistance they can provide. So your resistance will be 100 Ohms + your Potentiometer resistance. You need to measure the resistance across each potentiometer when you've set it to the value that starts your car. You can measure the resistance with any sort of multimeter.

Comment: Yes thanks that makes sense and gets me thinking. When I set the rig to read 15 degrees it has only ever been attached to coolant sensor plug.(not the actual sensor) It would be set at 15 and not change temp whilst driving as nothing to influence it. Do you think that if I put rig in place in such a way to include the actual sensor the temp will rise and fall in line with engine temp ? I had thought (probably incorrectly) that the potentiometers somehow prevented any fluctuations.

Comment: Is my next step to take reading of true engine temp then fit the rig and adjust to 15 degrease less. Then remove the rig and measure resistance between both end of the rig ?

Comment: Yes, you would use the multimeter to measure the resistance and it would give you a specific value in Ohms.

Answer (score 0):

ECU cannot have a corrupt file if it is based on a microcontroller, which would run then a compiled file, and if it were corrupted, the ECU would not start.

Usually the main ECU does not receive a voltage proportional to the temperature, but an encoded digital signal [0s, 1s] from a periferal board with a sensor and a microcontroller which calculates the signal from the voltage level, and then transmits the signal via a CAN bus to the main ECU. In that case you shoul hack the board where the sensor resides.

Answer (score 0):

If it is about hacking voltage, you have to make a "voltage divider" arrangement https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider

You have to put one pin of the resistor on the wire that comes back from the sensor to the ECU, and the other end of the resistor connected to the ECU's ground (GND).

By the way, I have to correct my previous answer, there can be 'not-compiled files in the ECU, and they can become corrupt and the ECU could still start up.

Regards